# Unable to resolve module react-native-fs

Tags: react-native, tensorflow, npm, expo

I'm learning react native and building and app that use the camera and it works fine.
Now I'm trying to make image classification but I'm getting this error after installing:

> @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native --legacy-peer-deps

I get this:

> Unable to resolve module react-native-fs from
> /Users/myuser/ALPR/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native/dist/bundle_resource_io.js:
> react-native-fs could not be found within the project or in these
> directories:   node_modules

I don't know what should I do, I tried installing react-native-fs but I got this:

> npm install react-native-fs npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE
> could not resolve npm ERR!  npm ERR! While resolving:
> @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native@0.8.0 npm ERR! Found:
> @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu@3.19.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu npm ERR!
> @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu@"3.19.0" from @tensorflow/tfjs@3.19.0 npm
> ERR!   node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs npm ERR!
> @tensorflow/tfjs@"^3.19.0" from the root project npm ERR!
> @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu@"3.19.0" from
> @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl@3.19.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl npm ERR!
> @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl@"3.19.0" from @tensorflow/tfjs@3.19.0
> npm ERR!     node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs npm ERR!
> @tensorflow/tfjs@"^3.19.0" from the root project npm ERR!  npm ERR!
> Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer
> @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu@"~3.11.0" from
> @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native@0.8.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native npm ERR!
> @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native@"^0.8.0" from the root project npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency:
> @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu@3.11.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu npm ERR!   peer
> @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu@"~3.11.0" from
> @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native@0.8.0 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native npm ERR!
> @tensorflow/tfjs-react-native@"^0.8.0" from the root project npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this
> command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an
> incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR!
> npm ERR! See /Users/macmac/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /Users/macmac/.npm/_logs/2022-08-22T12_14_25_319Z-debug-0.log

I'm using this tutorial: https://www.bam.tech/article/how-to-recognize-real-time-object-in-reactnative-for-dummies

Hopefully somebody can help me with this.
Thanks

This is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "alpr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.17.3",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^3.19.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "^0.8.0",
    "expo": "~46.0.8",
    "expo-camera": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-gl": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-gl-cpp": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-media-library": "~14.2.0",
    "expo-sharing": "~10.3.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Did you follow the steps on https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native? There are quite a few dependencies you need to install first.

Comment: I don't see any instructions. I read 3 dependencies (base64js buffer jpeg-js)but no instructions. I tried to install all of them but all of them gave me errors: "Found: @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu@3.19.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu
npm ERR!   @tensorflow/tfjs-backend-cpu@"3.19.0" from @tensorflow/tfjs@3.19.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs"

Comment: This seems a problem with node or npm version:
From the doc:

For RN < 0.57 and/or Gradle < 3 you MUST install react-native-fs at version @2.11.17!

For RN >= 0.57 and/or Gradle >= 3 you MUST install react-native-fs at version >= @2.13.2!

For RN >= 0.61 please install react-native-fs at version >= @2.16.0!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this by deleting the folder node_modules and then I used yarn install instead of npm.